# How to read a Durbin Watson Statistic (value of 3.5)

Tags: statistics

this may sound like a dumb question but I need to test a model for autocorrelation and the DW statistic was 3.52. There are 2 regressors and sample size is 32, so $d_L = 1.1$ and $d_h = 1.352$. Apparently this is above $d_H$ so should I reject the null and assume no autocorrelation, or because 3.52 is close to 4 should I assume negative autocorrelation?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If your null hypothesis is no autocorrelation, then you cannot "reject the null and assume no autocorrelation".  If you believe there may be negative autocorrelation, then perhaps you should be testing $4-d$ against the critical values

Comment: Can you clarify how to do that? What critical values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, if you are testing $H_0: \rho = 0$ against $H_0: \rho \neq 0$ then you should check both sides against the thresholds, i.e., $3.5$ for positive auto-correlation and $4-3.5$ for negative. Note that for this case your significance level should be $\alpha /2$ for each side (total of $\alpha$).

Comment: So if I wanted to test at 1% confidence I'd need to find a DW table that had 0.5% confidence with the same values?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Thanks again for the help- we're learning about instrumental variable estimation and I have a quick question on that. Would really appreciate the help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251599/instrumental-variable-regression-questions