# Instrumental Variable Regression Questions

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

We're learning about instrumental variable estimators and I just want to confirm my logic in these answers. Really appreciate the help!

[image]

a. True- If this happens and these variables are omitted, it will result in omitted variable bias.

b. False- having an equal amount of variables doesn't affect how the parameters are identified.

c. True- You can only use variables as instruments if they aren't included in your model.

d. True- Deriving these relationships will still result in linear variables.

Thanks again for the help

Comment: Sorry, it is too much into Economics/Econometrics this time. Maybe you should try to post it in https://economics.stackexchange.com or in https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help